110 volts is not enough to run more than two space heaters or one been here at a coffee pot at the same time
It gets pretty cold where I need a space heater in two rooms at the same time but I can't without tripping the circuit then I have to go outside put the switch it's just too cold to do that. How can I remedy this?

install more circuits

Most house circuits can only handle one space heater on each circuit, with maybe a light/radio/tv.  If you want two space heaters, you want two different circuits and without a coffee pot on it either, or expect to go out in the cold.

First of all, most likely the Voltage is 120, not 110. But that is NOT the problem. Power is Volts x Amps. The voltage is always the same (120V or 240V, depending on the circuit) and the part that varies is the current, measured in Amps. A typical circuit will be rated for 15A or 20A and if you go over the limit by a significant amount (say 25% or more) then the circuit will trip to protect the wires - and your house - from burning up.
The coffee pot is easy. Just turn off the space heaters for 10 minutes (or whatever it takes) to heat up your coffee. But that doesn't help for the space heaters.
A typical US (and 110V indicates old terminology US) older circuit will be 15A. Many newer circuits are also 15A, though circuits in certain rooms - e.g., kitchen and bathroom - are supposed to now be 20A. Because a space heater may run for a long time, it will be rated for 12A = 80% of 15A. For reasons, that means that almost all residential plug-in space heaters will be listed as 1500W. Doesn't matter if it is a $20 no-name or a $150 big brand with a fan and fancy extras. 1500W (125 x 12) is what you get.
That's 12A. Run two at the same time on the same circuit and that's 24A. 24A is definitely enough to trip a 15A circuit quickly. It may not trip a 20A circuit as quickly, but should within several minutes.
You have a few options:

Better heating system - That is the ideal. But it can (a) be expensive to install and (b) if you are in a rental that may not be an option at all. But heating is considered a requirement for occupancy in many locations, so if this is a permitted rental (as opposed to somebody's basement "off the books" apartment) then you may be able to pursue legal means to get a proper heating system installed (or fixed if there is one but it doesn't work properly).
More circuits - Adding a new 15A or 20A circuit is usually not a big deal. But it requires knowledge/skills/tools for a homeowner and a professional electrician in a rental. Add a new circuit and dedicate it to one of the space heaters and you have solved the problem.
Move things around - This often, but not always, is a solution. Sometimes a house or apartment simply doesn't have very many circuits. But often there are "extra" circuits available and you just have to figure out which circuits are connected to which receptacles. The catch, especially with space heaters, is that (a) you are not supposed to use extension cords - for good reason, because they can be a real fire hazard if undersized and also be a tripping hazard and have other problems and (b) without an extension cord you may trouble positioning a space heater where it can both heat the desired area and be sufficiently far away from curtains or other flammable items.


Please note that if you get such a cord, "at least 12 gauge" means the gauge number must be 12 or lower.  The larger size wire (with more current carrying capacity), the lower the gauge number.  Counter intuitive.
